# How to subquery inside a case statement in snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowflake and did some research on subquery in snowflake, but couldn't figure out this one problem. I am taking two values `Percentage` and `Cost` from Table `Temp1` in `CASE` Statement. So basically query is something like this

```
SELECT 
     EmpID,
     Percentage,
     CASE WHEN  Cost IS NOT NULL --from Temp1
          THEN ValueCost * Percentage / 100 -- Percentage from Temp1
          ELSE ValueCost END AS ValueCost
FROM FactTable
```

But since the syntax is like this for subquery. I am writing this query in snowflake like this:

```
SELECT 
     EmpID,
     (SELECT Perc FROM Temp1 limit 1) AS Percentage, -- this is working
     CASE WHEN (SELECT Cost FROM Temp1 WHERE Cost='221' limit 1) AS Cost -- from here not working
          THEN ValueCost * (SELECT Perc FROM Temp1 limit 1) AS Percentage / 100
          ELSE ValueCost END AS ValueCost
FROM FactTable
```

`Percentage` is Float and  `Cost` is numeric
Getting error: "Syntax error unexpeted AS and unexpected THEN"

Removed the AS part and modified it a bit but got the error:
"Invalid argument IFF (Number(38,0), Number(26,10), Number(15,2) )"

How can i correct this query? Any Help

Comment: What does “not working” mean? Does it error, in which case what is the error message or does it give the wrong values in which case what values does it give and what values do you expect?

Comment: I have edited the question. I am getting syntax error.

Comment: remove the `as cost`that is not allowed the same goes for `as percentage`

Comment: but what are you comparing the subquery to? maybe an `EXISTS`will be then correct comparision

Comment: @nbk Removed the AS part and modified it a bit but got the error: "Invalid argument IFF (Number(38,0), Number(26,10), Number(15,2) )"

Comment: can you provide for all tables involved a create table  and add some data, you got some major problem, if you want to make some calculations

Comment: @nbk ````Cost```` is  Numeric and ````Percentage```` is Float

Comment: Try JOINing to your temp table (and do give it a better name too)